# Left recursive in ANTLR4

Tags: recursion, antlr4

I have this below code :

```
grammar Hello;
expr :  expr ('*'|'/') expr
|   expr ('+'|'-') expr
|   (expr '[' expr ']')
|   ID
|   INT
;
ID : ID_LETTER (ID_LETTER | DIGIT)* ;  // INDENTIFIER
fragment ID_LETTER : [a-z] | [A-Z] | '_' ;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;
INT : DIGIT+ ;
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

I want to build a index expression but i have an error :

```
mutually left-recursive
```

in the 4th line of my code

I had tried :

```
expr '[' expr ']'// without (
```

The error was gone, but when i put an input : `a[2]` to the rule `expr`, it has an error:

```
Hello::expr:1:0: mismatched input 'a[2]' expecting {BOOL, ID, INT, FLOAT, STRING}
```

Comment: Its a known bug: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/564 . However, `(expr '[' expr ']')` and `expr '[' expr ']'` are equivalent, so you can just leave the parenthesis out. I'm not sure why you think they're different.

Comment: can you help me with the below question ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the error you mention.

Given the grammar:

```antlr
grammar Hello;

expr
 : expr ('*'|'/') expr
 | expr ('+'|'-') expr
 | expr '[' expr ']'
 | ID
 | INT
 ;

ID : ID_LETTER (ID_LETTER | DIGIT)* ;  // INDENTIFIER
fragment ID_LETTER : [a-z] | [A-Z] | '_' ;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;
INT : DIGIT+ ;
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

And a driver class that parses both `a[2]` and `a   [  2  ]`:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] tests = {"a[2]", "a   [  2  ]"};
    for (String test : tests) {
      HelloLexer lexer = new HelloLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(test));
      HelloParser parser = new HelloParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
      System.out.println(parser.expr().toStringTree(parser));
    }
  }
}
```

will print `(expr (expr a) [ (expr 2) ])` twice.